# How to stop asp.net mvc from redirecting to an error controller when an exception occurs during a json post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do you stop asp.net mvc from redirecting to an error page when it was a json post?  It keeps trying to redirect to the error path in my config file when an exception occurs and I need it to return the exception...also it doesn't even try and direct them to the correct path - it keeps looking for an Error.cshtml view under Home (the Home folder for views, as if it is trying to use my home controleler), when they are all under an Error folder/controller set up, which is clearly outlined in my config file:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Error">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/NotFound" />
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/Forbidden" />
</customErrors>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Catch the exception in the controller method?  If you handle the exception yourself, it shouldn't propagate to the error controller.

Comment: Ok, but also, why would it try to redirect to an Error view under my Home folder - it should be looking for it in the Error views folder?  Thanks!

Comment: Which one do you want... To not have an error redirection at all, or to have it redirect to the right place?  To keep things clearer, I would post the "redirection going to the wrong place" as a separate question, and add some detail to it.

Comment: Well, both are separate questions I guess, because for anything that isn't a json post/get, I do want to redirect to the error page (it will just log the exception behind the scenes).  I will post that as a separate question then.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1:
You can have BASE controller for all your controllers (it is good idea to have it) and in this controller you can override OnException method like this:

```
    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            // TODO
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
    }
```

Solution 2:
You can create Custom Action Filter to do the job and use method above. Than you can register this filter in global.asax or decorate only those controllers/actions you need.

general idea is to use:

```
Request.IsAjaxRequest()
```

Hope it helps. Good luck and have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by registering Application_Error event in Global.asax and then redirect it to an error controller with data in this way or you can perform what ever function you want depending upon error code

```
protected void Application_Error()
        {
            var exception = Server.GetLastError();
            var httpException = exception as HttpException;
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            var routeData = new RouteData();
            routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
            routeData.Values["action"] = "oops";
            routeData.Values["exception"] = exception;
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            if (httpException != null)
            {
                Response.StatusCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
                switch (Response.StatusCode)
                {
                    case 403:
                        routeData.Values["action"] = "NoAccess";
                        break;
                    case 404:
                        routeData.Values["action"] = "NotFound";
                        break;
                }
            }

            IController errorsController = new ErrorController();
            var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
            errorsController.Execute(rc);
        }
```

then make a controller with actions oops / NotAccess / NotFound like

```
public ActionResult oops(Exception exception)
        {
            //return Content("General failure", "text/plain");

           // return View();

        }

        public ActionResult NotFound()
        {
           // return Content("Not found", "text/plain");
          //  return View("oops");
        }

        public ActionResult NoAccess()
        {
            //return Content("Forbidden", "text/plain");
            //return View("oops");
        }
```

And Return your own view with proper information